# jquery click on radio button not working

Tags: jquery, radio-button, click

I have an HTML page exactly as below :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$("input:radio[name=aa]").click(function() {
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
});

function get_search_results(params) {
    alert('sdsds');
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="aa" />AA
<input type="radio" name="aa" />AB
<input type="radio" name="aa" />AC
</body>
</html>
```

So I was expecting whenever I click on any of the three radio buttons, it should redirect to `google`. But it does nothing ! Why ?

Comment: wrap code inside document ready handler or declare handler AFTER element has been added to the DOM, not before! Delegation could be an option but not really accurate in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script needs to be exected when the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=aa]").click(function() {
        window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
    });
});
```